# Label html string being read by screen reader

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I've got some dynamically generated html building a drop down menu using the Dojo library. I need to make my code Accessibility compliant and right now the screenreader looks at the menu item and reads it as plain html:

```
menu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "<a onclick=window.location.href='sampleurl.com'
                   href="sampleurl.com">Sample Link</a> ...
```

Excuse the onclick, it's for a different issue, but what I'm getting is basically:

*Tab down to first menu item*

Screenreader: "Less than a onclick equals window dot location dot href equals sampleurl"... etc

I've tried using aria-hidden, but the screen reader just reads that as text, I'm using voice over on Mac OS, but I need it compliant for JAWS as well. Any tips or advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**label is used for the label (which can be in HTML), not for putting the full link html tag.**

See on the following page how to use the Dojo library to generate menu items:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Menu.html

Example:

```
menu.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "Sample Link",
    onclick: function() {window.location.href='sampleurl.com';}}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to debug with a working example along with something stating what screen reader / browser combo you are using. At the bare minimum, show us the HTML output of your script, considering it is writing HTML for the screen reader to parse.

That being said, I suspect the missing / inconsistent quotes. Note that you start a string with double quotes, then go into the `onclick` attribute with no quotes around, then single quotes around its value, and then use double quotes around the `href`.

Alternatively, you are writing the entire string into the page and somehow HTML encoding it.

I suggest using a linting tool to check your JS.